# fill NaN values with mean based on another column specific value

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I want to fill the NaN values on my dataframe on column `c` with the mean for only rows who has as category `B`, and ignore the others.

```
print (df)
    Category   b    c
0   A          1  5.0
1   C          1  NaN
2   A          1  4.0
3   B          2  NaN
4   A          2  1.0
5   B          2  Nan
6   C          1  3.0
7   C          1  2.0
8   B          1  NaN
```

So what I'm doing for the moment is :

```
df.c = df.c.fillna(df.c.mean())
```

But it fill all the NaN values, while I want only to fill the 3rd, 5th and the 8th rows who had category value equal to `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine `fillna` with slicing assignment

```
df.loc[df.Category.eq('B'), 'c'] = (df.loc[df.Category.eq('B'), 'c'].
                                       fillna(df.c.mean()))

Out[736]:
  Category  b    c
0        A  1  5.0
1        C  1  NaN
2        A  1  4.0
3        B  2  3.0
4        A  2  1.0
5        B  2  3.0
6        C  1  3.0
7        C  1  2.0
8        B  1  3.0
```

---

Or a direct assignment with 2 masks

- [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) is the element wise equality operator.

```py
df.loc[df.Category.eq('B') & df.c.isna(), 'c'] = df.c.mean()

Out[745]:
  Category  b    c
0        A  1  5.0
1        C  1  NaN
2        A  1  4.0
3        B  2  3.0
4        A  2  1.0
5        B  2  3.0
6        C  1  3.0
7        C  1  2.0
8        B  1  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Andy for the answer that was perfect, beside I'd like to know which one is horizontally scalable for more data.

Comment: @saul: You are welcome. I think the 2nd is more scalable and clean :)

Answer (score -1):

This would be the answer for your question:

```
df.c = df.apply(
        lambda row: row['c'].fillna(df.c.mean()) if row['Category']=='B' else  row['c'] ,axis=1)
```